# Was the fortnite movement speed reduced for season 4?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I recently started playing Fortnite season 4, and I feel like my character is moving slower. I am not sure if this is because of a movement change, or maybe the character I am using is a tad larger so it just *appears* that I am moving slowly.

Was the fortnite movement speed changed with season 4?

Answer (score 4):

It does not look like movement speed was changed.  From spectating streams both before season 4 and watching present season 4 streams, everyone still seems to be moving at the same speed.

The [official season 4 Patch Notes](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/patch-notes/v4-0) do not mention that they slowed down movement in anyway.  If they did change something, it would likely be included in the notes, since that would be quite a significant change.  There does not appear to be any other posts claiming movement speed was changed in any way either, so it looks like it's just you.